# How to install programs on a separate hard drive?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I recently switched from Windows to Linux Mint and so far I'm absolutely loving it! However, I am wondering how can I choose the installation destination of various programs.

For example, I have a SATA drive that is 1TB and my SSD that is 128GB. I want to install Steam and various games on my SATA but whenever I try to run the installation, it doesn't let me choose a directory.

How can I choose a directory for the programs I install in Linux Mint?

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, it is unusual to specify an installation directory on Unix-like operating systems, because everything goes into a big hierarchy and the package manager sorts things out. You can still have multiple partitions, but these would be "everything below a specific path" -- for example, typical setups have a separate `/home` so users can't fill up the system disk.

Steam is a bit special here, though, because it runs with the permissions of the user, not the system administrator, so it cannot install anything into the regular paths.

So instead, all the installed files end up in a hidden directory in your home directory, `~/.local/share/Steam`.

If you want to have a partition just for games, the easiest way is to mount the partition there.

For the transition, you need to move the data over while Steam is not running.

```
$ cd ~/.local/share
$ pwd
```

Note down the full path here, we're going to need it later.

```
$ mv Steam Steam.old
$ mkdir Steam
$ sudo -i
```

Now we're working as root.

```
# lsblk -o +UUID
```

This gives you a list of the block devices and their UUIDs. Find the partition on the SATA disk, and note down the UUID. Next, mount the partition, changing the path and UUID as appropriate:

```
# mount UUID=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc /home/yourname/.local/Steam
```

If that worked, the partition should show up in `df` output. If not, you might need to prepare it first, that would be a separate question.

You can then make the change permanent, by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc /home/yourname/.local/Steam auto noatime 0 2
```

You will note that these are the same parameters as for the mount command, plus the file system type (`auto` for auto-detect), flags (`noatime` so access times aren't recorded, which is unnecessary for a games folder and causes a lot of writes to be generated while loading), and priorities for backups (`0`) and file system check (`2`, same as all but the root filesystem).

You can add `,nofail` to the flags if you want your system to boot normally if there is ever a problem with the file system, the downside of that is that you won't notice until you start Steam and it behaves like a fresh installation.

Test that the extra line works, by unmounting and mounting manually once:

```
# umount /home/yourname/.local/Steam
# mount /home/yourname/.local/Steam
```

If these succeed, you're good to go, exit the root shell

```
# exit
```

and copy the data over

```
$ rsync -Pra Steam.old/ Steam/
```

If you are missing the rsync utility, get it from your package manager.

Start Steam to verify everything made it over, then delete the old Steam directory

```
$ rm -rf Steam.old
```

And you're set.

Comment: This is the right answer, better than mine

Answer (score 1):

One way, on a `GNU/Linux` OS, using `mount --bind`:

- check which directory you want to 'export' on external drive, could be by example `/opt`
- what you can do is to move the directory, then mount it elsewhere on your OS

Todo so, as `root` (super)user:

```
shopt -s dotglob # if you are using bash. To match hidden files too with following wildcard*
mv /path/to/BIG/dir/* /path/to/directory/on/external/drive
mount --bind /path/to/directory/on/external/drive /path/to/BIG/dir
echo '/path/to/directory/on/external/drive /path/to/BIG/dir none defaults,bind 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

- the `mount --bind` mount temporary
- to make it permanent, the last line of code modify `/etc/fstab`. Take the time to edit it with your favorite `editor` to be sure there's no duplicates.

Then, you can transparently use your OS, and your BIG directory is moved.

Check `man mount | less +/--bind`

> **Bind mount operation**
> Remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else. The call is:
> `mount --bind olddir newdir`
> or by using this fstab entry:
> `/olddir /newdir none bind`
> After this call the same contents are accessible in two places.
> It is important to understand that "bind" does not create any second-class or special node in the kernel VFS. The "bind" is just another operation to attach a filesystem. There is nowhere stored information that the filesystem has been attached by a "bind" operation. The olddir and newdir are independent and the olddir may be unmounted.
> One can also remount a single file (on a single file). It’s also possible to use a bind mount to create a mountpoint from a regular directory, for example:
> `mount --bind foo foo`